# RegEx stops working when adding too many characters

Tags: regex, string, autoit

So I'm trying to return every Event inside a icr file (calender file based on vCalendar [.vcs]) with Regex (inside AutoIt). So an event inside a icr file starts with the line BEGIN:VEVENT and ends with END:VEVENT. I read the file to variable x and replace every new line in x with '[n', so the RegEx looks something like `(BEGIN:VEVENT\[n(?:\[n|[^\[]+)+END:VEVENT)` (begin, a number greater 0 of newlines or chars unequal to [ and end)
This works fine when I insert something like `'foo[nBEGIN:VEVENT[ndata[nEND:VEVENT[nbar'` but here comes the problem: I have two teststrings, upper one is returning a result, lower one isnt:

`1[nBEGIN:VEVENT[ndata1[nEND:VEVENT[nxxxxxxxxxxx[BEGIN:VEVENT[ndata2[nEND:VEVENT`
`1[nBEGIN:VEVENT[ndata1[nEND:VEVENT[nxxxxxxxxxxxx[BEGIN:VEVENT[ndata2[nEND:VEVENT`

You can test it for yourself at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/)

Comment: I just spotted an error in the syntax, it's [BEGIN not [nBEGIN, but if I fix it the problem doesn't occur anymore since it's returning both events as one... I'm totally stuck with this one. Because of the strange too many characters problem and because of the separation of the events

Comment: Is there anything like `[^\[]+ minus BEGIN:VEVENT` ?

Comment: Using regex in the way you've done is problematic because it will use an infinite number of backreferences.

Comment: so.. is there a better way for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone too lazy to take a look at the comments: [this](http://regex101.com/r/wC2hI2) is the solution l'L'l came up with, with some tweaking by me:

`(?:BEGIN:VEVENT)\[n(.+?)\[.(?:END:VEVENT)`

Answer (score 1):

Try using this pattern, it will not limit what is inside the `VEVENT[n`:

```
(BEGIN:VEVENT\[ndata(?:\[n|[^\[])+END:VEVENT)
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/zL2sK1

Comment: The problem is that the file content would be like [this](http://regex101.com/r/wM4nR1) as mentioned in my comment. The [BEGIN was a typo that I'm keeping because it ruins the effect of the error otherwise

Comment: I see; so are you wanting to capture everything except `1` and `[nxxxxx...` as in my example, but using the updated format showed above?

Comment: I am wanting to capture everything between BEGIN:VEVENT and END:VEVENT, including those lines, yes. And every BEGIN - END should be returned seperated

Comment: You added the 'data' to the regex which was just an example of any line in between the BEGIN and END, but removing the + is a good idea i guess... Still not fixing the problem of the never ending result

Comment: So more like [this](http://regex101.com/r/zL2sK1), or [this](http://regex101.com/r/yR3dH7)?

Comment: Actually according to the text to test it would be more like [this](http://regex101.com/r/tZ6xA9) or [this](http://regex101.com/r/pM3gM9), and the second one works better I guess. Understand what I'm talking about? I just corrected the string in the lower box. Also you can add an 'n' to the regex in the second one to get rid of the leading n in the result ([link](http://regex101.com/r/wC2hI2)) So this would work better than my first attempt in terms of longer texts?

Comment: Yes, it looks like the last one you've tweaked seems to work fine from what I can tell.